# Select SQL one row more

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a site with a database with user, I have three simple table:
- users
- user_profile (with an external key called: user_id to  table users)
- user_image_profile (with an external key called: user_id to  table users)

I want to select simply with a join this three table with the external key user_id.

Into my database there are three users, but when I run it retrieve me 4 users! one more than the users into the database, the repetaed user is the first.

Every user has a row into the tables users, user_image_profile and user_profile
Only a user doesn't have the row into user_image_profile.

I don't understand why return me 4 instead of three users.

```
SELECT *, `users`.`id` as user_id
FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN `user_profile` ON `user_profile`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `user_image_profile` ON `user_image_profile`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `users`.`created` desc LIMIT 12
```

Comment: how many records do you have in the `users` table?

Comment: How many records for the first user are in the user_profile and user_image_profile tables?

One of them will have more than one row for the user.

Comment: Check in user_profile Table, is there is two times id of first user?

Comment: I am assuming each user has one `user_profile` entry, if you query the `user_image_profile` table do you get 4 rows?  Sounds like you probably have a user with two images.  Since you are using `select *`, you should be able to tell what column has different data.

Comment: yes the problem was into the table user_profile.. a user with two profile.. error in registration of another script.. damn @bluefeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` query

```
SELECT *, `users`.`id` as user_id 
FROM (`users`) 
INNER JOIN `user_profile` 
ON `user_profile`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `user_image_profile` 
ON `user_image_profile`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `users`.`created` desc LIMIT 12
```

Comment: I have already tried with inner join, but return me the first user two times and the second, not third user because doesn't have a row into the table user_image_profile

Comment: @Alessandro can you create a sql fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Add in query

```
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Comment: He does not use aggregation, how is he supposed to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of GROUP BY